# javascript for loop vs forEach - why for loop seems to be faster than forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, foreach

Please, observe the following simple JavaScript code:

```js
var values = [];
var len = 1000000;
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) { values[i] = Math.random(); }
var ts1 = new Date(); 
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) { sum1 += values[i]; }
var ts2 = new Date(); 
values.forEach(function (val) { sum2 += val; });
var ts3 = new Date();

console.log(ts1, ts2, ts3);
console.log('for loop: ', ts2-ts1);
console.log('forEach: ', ts3-ts2);
```

When running this code I would expect the `forEach` version to be much faster than the plain for loop because as far as I know JavaScript arrays are not arrays, but hash tables. So, iterating 1,000,000 times with a for loop means doing 1,000,000 lookups into a hash table. Also, the number indices need to be converted to strings, because the hash table keys are strings, right?

Well, in reality the for loop runs a bit faster in most of the cases. In any case the difference is insignificant.

So, what am I missing? How come the for loop is as fast or even faster?

**EDIT 1**

This is not part of some real life application performance testing. I am just curious. Douglas Crockford in his lectures on JavaScript claims that JavaScript is very efficient with calling functions and I think he claims there that `forEach` should be faster than a for loop, because the former implements iteration as a native code in the browser, whereas the latter does hash table lookups.

Comment: different browsers will produce different results ... at a guess, you're using Chrome

Comment: `.forEach()` calls a function at each iteration

Comment: I take that back ... firefox the difference is insignificant, Chrome, forEach is 30 times slower

Comment: Use something like https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Don't lose sleep over it. When you're profiling the performance of actual applications, and not isolated micro-tests like this, the amount of time your code spends actually executing the array iteration is going to be a negligible amount either way. In some cases, you might find the `Array#forEach` could even be slightly faster/easier on memory because of the way the engine optimises reused functions.

Comment: I am just curious. I am not an active JavaScript developer, but I did some node.js programming. Anyway, I want to understand what is going on.

Comment: btw use `Date.now()` if all you want is to measure the time between two lines. The constructor's more appropriate when you actually care about having a `Date` object, e.g. you want to work in days of the month, account for leap-years, etc.

Comment: The `forEach` includes many checks

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou, even better, use `performance.now()` for browsers and `process.hrtime()` for node.

Comment: The js engine is a crazy thing. It knows a lot of common patterns and will optimise for them. Arrays aren't string-keyed either -- they're special in that they're indexed by integers.

Comment: @mark I have used code snippet for your code and also added few `console.log` stmts. When I ran the code 10 times, `for` loop was faster 6 times and `forEach` was faster 4 times. So looks like `for` loop is not always faster than `forEach`. What are your observations?

Comment: I do not have any observations. I think the information that for-loop should be avoided may have been true 5 years ago, but it is no longer so.